# Mysterious new line character when writing to a text file

Tags: python

```
def addCourse(studentId,courseAdd): #Registers the student's id to a class they input
    infile = open('student_database.txt','r')
    data = infile.readlines()
    outfile = open('student_database.txt','w')
    for line in data:
        if studentId+" " in line:
            line = line+" "+courseAdd
        outfile.write(line) #We rewrite all lines to the file whether they where modified or not
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()
```

This is a function that should add something like "course4" to the end of the first line of a text file. It should look something like this if the studentId in this instance is studentID

```
studentID course course2 course3 course4
studentID2 course course2 course3
```

however after the code runs it ends up looking like this

```
studentID course course2 course3
 course4studentID2 course course2 course3
```

Why is `course4` added to the wrong line?

Comment: Is the error reproducible if you write to a different file than the one you're currently reading from?

Comment: Each line of data you read from the file already has a newline character at the end of it.  If you append something to the line, it will go after the newline, and therefore appear on the next line.

Comment: Pyhton won't magically handle a newline character. You need to tell it to. Change `line = line+" "+courseAdd` to something like `line = line.replace("\n", " "+courseAdd+"\n"`). As an aside, it's not a great idea to open the file twice in read/write mode and you shouldn't be writing more documentation that code in the case of something this straightforward.

Comment: The result also depends on whether the `courseAdd` argument passed when calling the function contains any new line characters, which you didn't show.

Comment: @BrianJoseph Python *does* magically add a newline character in many cases. For example, `print` adds a newline without needing to tell it to.

Comment: @mkrieger1, I'm not talking about python adding newlines when printing. I'm just stating that in the context of adding characters to a string python won't "know" that you want to remove the already-present newline and move it to the end again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each line of data you read from the file already has a newline character at the end of it. If you append something to the line, it will go after the newline, and therefore appear on the next line.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60480613/mysterious-new-line-character-when-writing-to-a-text-file#comment106994109_60480613)